# Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, discriminant-analysis

I have a dataset with two classes and I want to apply Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis. To train the model, in what order do I need to compute the following:The within-class scatter,The sample means of each class, The between-class scatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both within class and between class scatter matrices need mean vectors calculated. So, you need to first calculate the mean vectors for each class and then the scatter matrixes in any arbitrary order you like.

Comment: Hi, is that correct that LDA/FDA can only generate 2 output?